# trying to make table using div without display table

Tags: jquery, html, css

*I am trying to create table without table tag and using div here i used this style method for top head shown below*

```
.fixtable {   
              width: 12%;
              background-color: darkgray;
              float: left;
              border-bottom: none;
              display: inline-block;
              margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
          }
```

*another is this for dynamic content*

```
.fltLft{float:left;}
.fltRgt{float:right;}
.dvWd5Per{width:5%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.dvWd10Per{width:10%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.dvWd15Per{width:15%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.dvWd25Per{width:25%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.padCellPx{padding:5px;}
```

*and the html is shown below*

```
     <div>
        <div class="fixtable">Sr.No.</div>
        <div class="fixtable">Product Name</div>
        <div class="fixtable">Update/Delete</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.objlst)
        {
            Model.rowNumber++;
            <div>
                <div class="fltLft dvWd5Per">
                    <div class="padCellPx">
                        @Model.rowNumber
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fltLft dvWd5Per">
                    <div class="padCellPx">
                        @item.ProductName
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fltLft dvWd5Per">
                    <div class="padCellPx">
                        <button type="button">
                            <font style="color:#000;">View</font>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

*How can i create the table without using the display:table using basic 'margin' and 'padding','float'*

*Here is the image below :-*

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iTB2.png)

*Here is the code changed below of CSS*

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {

}

.table, .header, .row {
    width: 100%;
}

.productBody {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.col {
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
}
.col1 {
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
}
```

*and for HTML also:-*

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col">Sr.No.</div>
    <div class="col">Product Name</div>
    <div class="col">Store Name</div>
    <div class="col">Company Name</div>
    <div class="col">Description</div>
    <div class="col">Quantity</div>
    <div class="col">Gross Amount</div>
    <div class="col">Update/Delete</div>
</div>
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.objlst)
    {
        Model.rowNumber++;
        <div class="row productBody">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @Model.rowNumber
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @item.ProductName
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @item.StoreName
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @item.CompanyName
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @item.desc
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    @item.amt
                </div>
                <div class="col1">
                    &nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn viewButton" onclick="openAddressCont1(@Model.rowNumber)">
                        <font style="color:#000;">View</font>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    }       
</div>
```

Comment: *create the table without using the display:table* -- But why? In fact this seems like tabular data, why not just use a regular `table`??

Comment: Sorry my client needs it that way without table

Comment: Then it is your responsibility (*as a developer and an IT professional*) to educate your client on the absurdity of this requirement. Educate the client about the way it breaks semantics and is just not right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the following way to make a table based on DIVs.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .header {
            background: red;
        }

        .table, .header, .row {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .col {
            width: 33.3333333%;
            float: left;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="col">
                Row Number
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Product Name
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                dasd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="row productBody">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        Row #1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        Product A
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="button" value="View"/>
                    </div>
                <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        Row #2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        Product B
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="button" value="View"/>
                    </div>
                <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes it works but a blank column disrupts the design how to fix that issue in dynamic

Comment: Please, post an image so that I can help you.

Comment: I have posted the image please help me in this issue